# What's the best solution to track monthly bandwith usage across multible devices

Tags: monitoring, network-traffic

Szenario:

I have two workstations and some muötimedia devices with an internet connection at home. I switched my ISPs contract since years and YEA they track my usage and will feed me with just 2000 Mbit's if I use to much of my bandwidth

How to track this when there is not only a computer where you can put some software on easily but some hardware with internet connections to that serves netflix for example?

What is the best way to track my bandwidth usage to avoid to be throttled by my ISP and have the chance to stop using the internet before we have used 300 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't rely on software solution running on all devices at your LAN, i would suggest tracking the WAN port on your router.

Most routers today have network statistics information that is accessible using the router's web administration interface.
You can track your current bandwidth usage from there.

If your router has support for SNMP, you can setup alerts to be sent to one of your devices for monitoring.